# Proper way to position bullet list in <ul> when size of list can be change

Tags: html, css

Try to positioning my list so it can be align well when the font size can change

if list-position-style: outside the bullet list is not align well

```
ul{
    
  }
<ul>
<li style="font-size :30px; text-align: justify;">12345 67890 12345 67890</li>
<li style="text-align: justify;">12345</li>
<li style="text-align: justify;">678910</li>
</ul>
```

[image]

if list-position-style: inside  the bullet list is align well, but the second row is not indent well

```
ul{
    
    list-style-position: inside;
  }

<ul>
    <li style="font-size :30px; text-align: justify;">12345 67890 12345 67890</li>
    <li style="text-align: justify;">12345</li>
    <li style="text-align: justify;">678910</li>
    </ul>
```

[image]

What's the best option to fix it?

Comment: Share the HTML/CSS code you have done so far

Comment: How exactly do you change the font size? Inline style? <font> tag? adding a CSS class?

Comment: Best option if you want more control, is to replace the "native" bullets with a pseudo element, that you can apply formatting to as you like.

Comment: @AbinThaha i've append the source code to the question

Comment: @SalmanA the list is read an external html file,  so i read the external file and append to a <div>

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom list to do so, check the snippet below.

I created a li bullets using before pseudo-class and this way you can easily manage the design of the same.

```css
ul li:first-child {
    font-size: 18px;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
}

li {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

li::before {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #000;
    margin-right: 10px;
    flex: 1;
    max-width: 10px;
    min-width: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>1324e32</li>
    <li>1dsd</li>
    <li>1asd</li>
    <li>1das</li>
    <li>asdaasda1asda1asda1asda1asda1asda1asda1asda1asda1asda1asda1asda1asda1asda1asda1asda1asda11</li>
</ul>
```

**Update**

li with long content breaking into 2 lines which was not working as expected, issue fixed.

Comment: if the last <li>  has long words , it will make 2 row, and  the second row not align well with the first row

Comment: @lauwispremium, that can be fixed. We are using flexbox, so